# Partner Account and Deploy

Tags: partner-communities

I have a developer account and would like to try AppExchnage. 
I registered in [partners.salesforce.com](http://partners.salesforce.com) five days ago and do not see any feedback. How can I call to SF support to remind about my request.
Is there any short way for developers purposes to deploy App and install this App from another account? Does SF have sandbox for AppExchange?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a FAQ where you register to become a partner along with a couple of videos. You'll eventually be contacted by a representative of the ISV program who'll want to discuss your product plans with you. As I recall, once that's done they'll admit you to the partner community and you file a case to get access to Environment Hub and other things. I believe some of these things have been changing, so the FAQ will have the latest info.